# Why this recursive catch is sometimes getting undefined for the .then parameter?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm new in debugging async code, and I get lost in the debugger flow. Can you spot why the greet parameter in .then(greet) is sometimes undefined?

```js
var tomsGreet = "Hello"

var thinkSomething = (idea) => {
  console.log("I'm thinking")
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject)=>{
    if(Math.round(Math.random() * 1))
      {
        fulfill("Hello Tom, how is your " + idea)
      }
    else{
      reject("Error found")
    }
    fulfill("Hello Tom, how is your " + idea)
  })
}

var respondToTom = (response) => {
    return this.thinkSomething("dog")
        .catch((error) => {
            console.warn(`Error in thinking`)
            if (error === 'Error found') {
                console.log(`Retrying thinking`)
                return this.respondToTom(this.tomsGreet)
            }
            else { throw error; }
        })
        .then((greet) => {
            if (greet == undefined){
              console.error("Ups undefined")
            }
            console.log(greet)
        });
}

this.respondToTom(tomsGreet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you recursively call `responseToTom()` from the `.catch()` handler, you are relying on the fact that `responseToTom()` will return a promise that resolves to a value.  But, in this code:

```
    .then((greet) => {
        if (greet == undefined){
          console.error("Ups undefined")
        }
        console.log(greet)
    });
```

You aren't returning any value so that will always resolve to an `undefined` value.  You probably want to add `return greet` to that `.then()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Change to put the `.catch` after `.then`

```
var respondToTom = (response) => {
    return thinkSomething("dog")
    .then((greet) => {
        if (greet == undefined){
            console.error("Ups undefined")
        }
        console.log(greet)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(`Error in thinking`)
        if (error === 'Error found') {
            console.log(`Retrying thinking`)
            return respondToTom(tomsGreet)
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If I do that and something fails in the then, I wouldn't know where the failure origin was in thinkSomething or in the .then, would I?

Comment: Not directly but: - there is no real risk in your current `.then` and you made a test in catch